# Combine title of document and url of document in twig

Tags: url, twig, title

I have an array of results (= documents) which is displayed in a table. I would like to add the url of each result to the title, so when a users clicks on the title, the user is directed to the file (document). How can I do this? Where can I add the necessary information the code below?

```
{% for res in results %}
     <tr>
         <td> {{doc[##preview].title|default('')}} </td>
           ....
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Too few details, what attributes does a `document` have? Where are they located?

Comment: Please provide more information about **Document** and `results`. what do you mean by `doc`.